# Permutations (People Arranged in Rows)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

9 people are to sit in 3 rows of 3 people.
'Jim' and 'Bob' must be in the same row.
How many ways can this be arranged?

I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

I see it as one row has to have 2 people together, but the row needs 3 total, so I would guess:

```
3!
```

You then have to place this row in one of the 3 rows, so it becomes `3! x 3`

You then have to arrange the next 6 people in the remaining seats, so `6!`.

So my guess is:

```
3! x 3 x 6! = 12,960 ways
```

However, I feel that this is wrong.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to account for the third person who sits in the same row as Jim and Bob.

**Method 1:**  Here is a modified version of your solution.

There are $3$ ways to choose the row in which Jim and Bob sit.  There are $7$ ways to choose the third person who sits in that row.  There are $3!$ ways to arrange the people in that row.  There are $6!$ ways to arrange the remaining six people in the other six seats.
$$3 \cdot 7 \cdot 3! \cdot 6!$$

**Method 2:**  We seat Jim and Bob, then sit the remaining people.

There are nine ways to seat Jim.  Since Bob must sit in the same row, there are two ways to sit Bob in one of the remaining seats in that row.  The seven remaining people can be seated in the seven remaining seats in $7!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$9 \cdot 2 \cdot 7!$$
permissible seating arrangements.

Comment: Wow thanks!  I never even considered method 2!  That is much more clear than the method I was reaching for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @joe_04_04  You are welcome.

Comment: Method one could be reduced to 3 * 3! * 7!, correct?

Comment: @joe_04_04  Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I know this is asking quite a bit, but I'm trying to follow the same logic with the same problem, but 4 people per row (12 people total).  I can't seem to understand how to apply the first method.

Method 1: ?
Method 2: 12 ways to seat Jim, 3 ways to seat Bob, then 10! = 12 x 3 x 10!

Comment: In your new version of the problem, there are still $3$ ways to choose the row in which Jim and Bob sit.  Now, there are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select two other people for their row.  The four people in that row can be seated in $4!$ ways.  The other eight people can be seated in the remaining seats in  $8!$ ways.  $$3\binom{10}{2} \cdot 4!8!$$  A blend of the first and second methods:  Choose the row in which Jim and Bob sit.  We can seat Jim in the chosen row in $4$ ways and Bob in $3$ ways.   The remaining people can be seated in $10!$ ways, yielding $$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 10!$$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so in your method 1 in the original problem, you used "7 ways to choose the third person who sits in that row" to represent `7C1`, which is just `7`.  I didn't consider it was using "choose," so I wasn't applying `10C2` in the new problem, I was using `10! x 9!`.  I do wonder why it is `10C2` and not `10P2`, doesn't the order matter?

Comment: The order does matter.  The order of the people in the row occupied by Jim and Bob is accounted for by multiplying by $4!$ after we choose who is in that row.

Comment: Amazing! You have cleared this all up for me!  Thank you very much for your extended and gracious help, @N.F.Taussig